# How can I use UIActivityViewIndicator in my app delegate?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios5, uiactivityindicatorview

I've got a method that is in my app delegate that is called to pull information from a web server. Is there a way to easily incorporate UIActivityViewIndicators into the app delegate? Everything I've found so far online shows the Indicator requiring to be added as a subview. Is this doable? If so, can you point me in the right direction on where to find this?

[edit]
I'm using a storyboard instead of xibs.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can easily add a `UIActivityViewIndicators` with few lines of code:

```
UIActivityIndicatorView *aiv = [[[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhite] autorelease];  
aiv.center = self.window.rootViewController.view.center;
[self.window.rootViewController.view addSubview:aiv];
[aiv startAnimating];
```

But there are a lot of open source project like [MBProgressHUD](http://www.cocoacontrols.com/platforms/ios/controls/mbprogresshud) that gives you more stylish indicator, with other additions..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can add the UIActivityIndicatorView directly from your AppDelegate. There should be an object or property of your UIViewController inside your AppDelegate. There, you can add it.

```
[viewController.view addSubView:activityIndicatorView];
```